# Large image for semantic segmentation task -- Pytorch runs out of memory

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have large images (256,256) of ImageNet, and I want to train for a semantic segmentation task. The output will thus be `(B,Classes,C,H,W)`. I have 256 classes. For CrossEntropyLoss or NLL as defined by pytorch I need to use dtype long [Docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html).

However a tensor of (256,3,256,256) of type long is just over 0.4GB of memory making it impossible to train in GPU for batch sizes over 4 (considering that the model takes significant memory as well as backprop algorithm).

I am using Google Cloud T4 with 16GB of memory. **Are there any tricks I can do for this problem in order to train for larger batch sizes?** For the batch sizes I can train it would take months to finish training.

Comment: Try [AMP](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html)?

Comment: This problem is commonly encoutered in deep learning, and has lead to the development of the GroupNorm (https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08494) which enables very good results despite small batches. That won't solve your problem per se, but the size of 4 should not be such a problem anymore with that

Comment: @trialNerror nice paper. Thanks for sharing. Training would still take months however :(

Comment: @hkchengrex this doesn't solve the problem, maybe I will be able to increase to batch size of 6 or 8 but the improvement will be insignificant. Please correct me if I am wrong.